# Migrating a Pycharm project to VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, visual-studio-code

I have a project that I set up in Pycharm with a repo in GitHub. I would like to change IDE's to VS Code and need help setting up the project in VS Code

I have tried to open the entire folder in VS Code and I am able to access it fine. However, none of my imports within the package work.

For e.g.:

```py
from my_package import my_module
```

This works fine in Pycharm, but fails in VS Code

Need instructions on the setup to avoid renaming all the imports in the package

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to add your workspace folder to the python interpreter used by vscode?

If I recall correctly, you can change your settings.json file and set your pythonpath from there:

My settings.json file contains the following variable that is set:

```
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows":
     {
            "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
     }
```

and this should add your project folder to sys.path